# How do I infinitely scroll a background image using pygame in python

Tags: python, pygame

Well, I tried scrolling each image and appending another behind one another
but it keeps on displaying a grey surface behind the images.
Here a scratch file for my code:

```
import math 
import pygame as py 
  
py.init() 
  
clock = py.time.Clock() 
  
FrameHeight = 600
FrameWidth = 1200
  
# PYGAME FRAME WINDOW 
py.display.set_caption("Endless Scrolling in pygame") 
screen = py.display.set_mode((FrameWidth, 
                              FrameHeight)) 
  
# IMAGE 
bg = py.image.load("./Data/sky_background/bg2.png").convert()
# bg.set_colorkey((108,108,108))
# bg = py.transform.scale(bg, [FrameWidth, FrameHeight])
  
# DEFINING MAIN VARIABLES IN SCROLLING 
scroll = 0
  
# CHANGE THE BELOW 1 TO UPPER NUMBER IF 
# YOU GET BUFFERING OF THE IMAGE 
# HERE 1 IS THE CONSTATNT FOR REMOVING BUFFERING 
tiles = math.ceil(FrameWidth / bg.get_width()) + 1
  
# MAIN LOOP 
while 1: 
    # THIS WILL MANAGE THE SPEED OF 
    # THE SCROLLING IN PYGAME 
    clock.tick(33) 
  
    # APPENDING THE IMAGE TO THE BACK 
    # OF THE SAME IMAGE 
    i = 0
    while(i < tiles): 
        screen.blit(bg, (bg.get_width()*i+scroll, 0)) 
        i += 1
    # FRAME FOR SCROLLING 
    scroll -= 20
  
    # RESET THE SCROLL FRAME 
    if abs(scroll) > bg.get_width(): 
        scroll = 0
    # CLOSINF THE FRAME OF SCROLLING 
    for event in py.event.get(): 
        if event.type == py.QUIT: 
            quit() 
  
    py.display.flip() 
  
py.quit()
```

The code works perfectly fine (at least, since I've tested it) but my only problem is just the grey surface behind each images.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without giving us the actual image files it is impossible to tell why these gray squares are happening. However, it is most likely that your images have a gray background within the file, in which case you can go to an online website like [www.remove.bg](http://www.remove.bg) and remove the background (in which case you need to use convert_alpha() instead of convert() when loading the image. Alternatively, you can set the colorkey on the image to whatever the color of the gray background is. However, if you do this you must be careful as it removes all pixels of that color, including those that are a part of the image and not the background!

If you have any problems please let me know, and hopefully this helps!